# How to match a rewritten URL string with hyphens to a string that might have 1 hyphen in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, hyphenation

I'm rewriting a URL with hyphens using `item_name` column. for instance `animals of the planet-v9` to `http://example.com/book/animals-of-the-planet-v9` with `str_replace(' ','-',$item_name)`. How I'm approaching back to MySQL is:

[image: it contains 1 hyphen in item_name]

```sql
$item_name = str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET['item_name']);
SELECT * FROM table where item_name LIKE '% $item_name %'
```

"animals-of-the-planet **-v9**" Becomes "animals of the planet **v9** "

URL: example.com/animals-of-the-planet-v9

The above query matches 0 results, I noticed any of column that contains hyphen - is not matching because sometimes it needs one original hyphen other than the rewritten ones in string. I also tried with = and LIKE in query. How do I figure this out where I can have a pretty simple URL containing hyphens without any numeric ids?

Comment: Please show sample input and output URLs.

Comment: I updated question. It's quite simple. Mysql value contains 1 hyphen *a b c d e-f. After creating a slug with hyphens *a-b-c-d-e-f* i again remove all hyphens after it getting from url slug *a b c d e f* that also removes one original hyphen before *f*.  that was supposed to be matched that column again. When it removes all hyphens it doesn't match the value.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$item_name = $_GET['item_name'];
SELECT * FROM table where REPLACE(item_name, ' ', '-') = '$item_name'
```

Note - Escape $item_name before using it. To prevent your query from mysql injection.

Comment: actually, `animals of the planet-v9` is real value in mysql. after rewriting it became `animals-of-the-planet-v9 ` now i got it back in PHP with $_GET method with replacing all hyphens now it became `animals of the planet v9` notice one hyphen `-` before `v9` is also removed which is required again to match the original string.

Comment: @RanaHaroon, Query it self will convert the item_name to `animals-of-the-planet-v9` before matching it with `$item_name`. Try the code once.

Comment: I gave it try, it actually needs 'animals of the planet-v9" again. But after replacing hyphens from slug with str_replace() it also removes the one required hyphen before **v9** here i need the trick.

Comment: @RanaHaroon, I've not replaced the original slug, i'm just using the slug as it is please take a look at code.

`$item_name = $_GET['item_name'];`

That means the $item_name will be `animals-of-the-planet-v9` and query will replace all item names before matching.

Comment: I got it. but query will replace all hyphens. But it ll still need 1 hyphen before **v9** for matching.

Comment: @RanaHaroon, Query will replace spaces to hyphens, not your actual $item_name from url.

Comment: you mean query sets column value with hyphens first then matches?

Comment: @RanaHaroon, Yes exactly.

Comment: yes, that worked. couldn't think that way. Thank you